# What is the Java equivalent of Regexp::Assemble?

Tags: java, regex, perl

I came across the Perl module [Regexp::Assemble](http://p3rl.org/Regexp%3a%3aAssemble) which takes an arbitrary number of regular expressions and assembles them into a single regular expression that matches all that the individual ones.

Is there any similar library for Java? It will be quite tedious to write a combined regex for each and every input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[regexp](http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/wiki/RegexpOptimization) might help you... The link points to an example that does similar to what you want, I am not sure if it will work with Regex dictionary or not though. Also, you might want to email the author and I am sure he can help you figure out a solution for your exact use case.

Comment: Thank you. Let me check the link

Comment: Hey, If you don't mind can you please let us know how can you solve this problem, I have to do a similar thing now. Can we just have a regex as part of the String[] of the example.

Comment: This is what I did. I wrote all the regexps in a separate file. Whenever I need to generate common regexp, I will read those regexps from the file into an String array and pass to RegExpUtils.convertListToRegexp(true, fileContent) method. Which will return optimized regexp.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a matter of `OR`ing the regexes. e.g. if you have the regexes `[abc]+` and `[xyz]+` you could combine these with `(regex1|regex2)` which is: `([abc]+|[xyz]+)`. Adding more regexes is just a matter of adding more `|` clauses. So you don't really need a 'generator' so much as a loop. For example:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

List<String> regexlist = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
    regexlist.add(line);
} 

String regex = "(?:" + StringUtils.join(regexlist, "|") + ")";
```

Comment: Thank you. But I afraid its not only about ORing. See the output from Regex::Assembly module (?^:(?:[abc]+|[xyz]+)) for your example reg-ex's. I think there might be performance hit if we simply performing ORing.

Comment: Clearly `Regex::Assembly` will produce a different output; it does analysis of the contained regexes. You should first test the naive solution, and only if there is a performance problem attempt something more complex. Regarding your example: a non-capturing group is better; I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, I've written a script with Regexp::Assemble which will generate the set of REs I want and write them to a file, to be read in by the main java app - would that work for you ?